# Creating a lookup table from scratch

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, customization, crm, lookup

I have a crm dynamics form and I want to add a new lookup box to it.  I understand how to add existing lookups, but how do I create a brand new lookup where the table or data do not exist yet?

This is trivial in sql, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in crm dynamics.

Any someone please point me in the write direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create your related entity if it does not exist
- Add a new N:1 relationship from your primary entity to the related entity
- This adds a new lookup field to your primary entity which you can then add to forms and views.